# Swift is not fetching data on Pokedex app

Tags: swift, url, fetch

When I run my app, the data isn't showing up in the simulator. Here's how I've set it up.

```
let baseURL = "https://pokedex-bb36f.firebaseio.com/pokemon.json"

init() {
    fetchPokemon()
}

func fetchPokemon() {
    guard let url = URL(string: baseURL) else { return }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data?.parseData(removeString: "null,") else { return }
        guard let pokemon = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Pokemon].self, from: data) else { return }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.pokemon = pokemon
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
```

I've checked out a few other apps with similar code and they are working fine. I can't find the error in mine.

Here is the link to the whole project: https://github.com/jefferymason/Pokedex-SwiftUI.git

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a JSON decoding error? By using `try?` instead of `do/try/catch`, you're throwing away any chance at seeing a decoding error. You're also not checking for an error in your `URLSession`

Comment: How do you tell when your pokemon are loaded? If you call fetchPokemon() and then immediately try to look for results in your pokemon array as soon as the function returns, it won't work. Your URLSession call is async, and will return before the results are available.

Comment: Where does a guy named 'Pokemon' come from?  What does a guy named 'self.pokemon' come from?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't figure it out, but I did start from scratch and took a different approach. This version is working. Check it out if you want: https://github.com/jefferymason/PokedexSwiftUI.git